# Error "expected an indented block" in my Phyton Calculator

Tags: python, python-requests

I have searched for hours to try to find a error in my codes and I didn't get anything!
Please help me!

[[image: This is the codes that I have write[![][1]]]
[[image: Error]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpnRm.png)
[[image: This is the codes that I have write]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAsD5.png)

Comment: Jovem, este é o [pt.so]. Sua pergunta deve estar **em português**. E, por favor, poste o código como texto e não em imagens. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta a qualquer momento.

Comment: Primeiro: o idioma aqui é português, então, por favor, traduza sua pergunta. Segundo: não poste seus códigos como imagem, o [pt.so] tem suporte para códigos, basta fazer o [tour] para aprender. Terceiro: pela mensagem de erro, você errou na indentação.

Answer (score 1):

Cara pela imagem não dá pra ver direito, mas você não está indentando o código corretamente. Por exemplo quando define a função btnClick():

```
...
def btnClick(numbers):
    global operator
    operator = operator + str(numbers)
    text_Input.set(operator)

cal = Tk()
...
```

Recomendo consultar a recomendação do Python sobre a obrigatoriedade da indentação.
Aqui um tutorial http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php